# Selenium-Nunit How to wait for a several images

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, nunit

i would like to ask you, how to wait for a multiple pictures to show(pictures are showing one by one). in JAVA - Junit is a code for multiple waiting

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.(xpath("//div[@class = 'minions']//img"), number: 5));
```

I am using Nunit (C#) and dont know how to do something similar to junit wait. Seems like c# doesn't have anything like this.
Can somebody help me please?

Comment: You can use while loop.  while( numofElements<5)  num  ofElements = driver.findelements(by.xpath()).size()  sleep(200) and add maximum wait interval in while loop condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `driver.FindElements(By.XPath("...")).Count` along with an explicit wait:

```
var xpath = "//div[@class = 'minions']//img";
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(By.XPath(xpath)).Count == 5);
```

You can always create an extension method if you want something easier to reuse:

```
public static class WebDriverWaitExtensions
{
    public static void UntilNumberOfElementsExist(this WebDriverWait wait, By locator, int number)
    {
        wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(locator).Count == number);
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
var xpath = "//div[@class = 'minions']//img";
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

wait.UntilNumberOfElementsExist(By.XPath(xpath), 5);
```